# Uniqueness of ODE solution with absolute function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE   $dy/dx = 2\sqrt{|y|}$.
Suppose I was given initial conditions $y(1) = 1$ for $y > 0$ and $y(-3) = -1$ for $y < 0$, and from these combining with y(x) = 0, I could find a solution.
But, for example, if I keep the same initial condition for y > 0 and change the one for $y < 0$ to $y(-4)=-1$, I will have a different solution.
In this case, for the same initial condition $y(-3) = -1$, we have multiple solutions.

I want to ask is this solely because that the absolute function is not differentiable at 0, thus it fails the conditions of the Picard existence and uniqueness theorem? Or is the answer more subtle and I need more explanation for this non-uniqueness?

Thank you

Comment: What you're writing makes no sense (to me, at least). An initial condition is a value $y(x_0)$ given at some point $x=x_0$. And that value may be positive or negative or zero (and it's zero that's the interesting case here), but not positive and negative at the same time.

Comment: Hi, I just made my question to be more specific. I hope it has been clearer now! Thank you

Comment: It's still worded a bit weirdly, but I think I see what you meant now, you're saying that you can get a unique solution if you specify $y(x_1)=y_1<0$ and $y(x_2)=y_2>0$ where $x_2-x_1$ is large enough. And that's true, but that's providing boundary conditions at *different times*, which is not the normal thing we do in IVPs. Instead of thinking "what conditions can I impose to make the solution unique", I would think dynamically: starting from, say, $y(-3)=-1$ and going forward in time, what can start to happen for $x \geq -2$?

Answer (score 1):

Picard-Lindelof doesn't apply because $f(x,y)=2\sqrt{|y|}$ is not Lipschitz as a function of $y$, due to an infinite slope at $y=0$. (Differentiability is not actually an issue, it is just used in the common "elementary" form of Picard-Lindelof to avoid explaining the term Lipschitz. As a concrete example to support this remark, the IVPs of $y'=|y|$ always have unique solutions.)

However, the failure of the hypotheses of Picard-Lindelof does not *immediately* imply that the solutions are not unique.

In this specific problem, you see that $y \equiv 0$ is a solution, but you can also see that there are solutions with $y(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0$ but $y \not \equiv 0$, such as $y=\operatorname{sign}(x) x^2$. So the solutions aren't unique.

I can't really understand what you mean about initial conditions for $y>0$ or $y<0$. In actuality *none* of the IVPs of this particular equation have unique solutions; if $y(x_0)>0$ then you can go backward in time until you hit $y=0$, and then you have non-uniqueness after that. Similarly if $y(x_0)<0$ then you can go forward in time and eventually uniqueness will break down.

Comment: Hi, I just edited my question to make it clearer! Thank you